# Mysql select union error

Tags: mysql, union

I am trying to display all records from table1 even if the catid not existing in table2 (all employee in table2 should have all catid from table1 with 0 days if not exising in table2) with the following sql query but getting an error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'catid' in 'group statement'
```

SQL

```
select empid,days from table2 
union 
select catid from table1 
group by empid, catid;
```

table1

```
catid
1
2
3

table2
empid catid days (computed column count(*))
1000    1    1
1000    3    1
```

Expected result:

```
empid  catid  days
1000    1    1
1000    2    0 <---catid 2 and days 0 if catid is not existing in table2 for empid 1000
1000    3    1
```

Comment: Well, for starters, your UNION will fail because the field types in the union do not match - they don't even have the same count - you can only union like with like. As for the days field, you should give us data - not just - (i.e. hyphens) - what do you think the sum of a hyphen is?

Comment: Both queries in `UNION` HAVE to select the same number of columns. And from the syntax it is not clear if the `group by` is supposed to apply to the second query or to the `UNION` results, use braces around the queries to make it clear.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: LEFT JOIN not giving all records from table2 but those catid s existing in table2

Comment: *"computed column count(*)"* ??? MySQL does not have computed columns ... Is the `table2` shown a base table or the result set of a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it this way:

### Table1:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table1;
+-------+
| catid |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Table2:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table2;
+-------+-------+
| empid | catid |
+-------+-------+
|  1000 |     1 |
|  1000 |     3 |
|  1001 |     1 |
|  1002 |     2 |
|  1002 |     3 |
+-------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Query:

```
SELECT
    t2.empid,
    t1.catid
    ,COUNT(t3.empid) as days
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                DISTINCT empid,t1.catid 
            FROM table2 AS t2 
            LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON (t1.catid>0)
            ) AS t2 -- Getting all empids from table2 and catids from table1
ON (t1.catid=t2.catid)
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t3 ON (t2.empid=t3.empid AND t3.catid=t2.catid)
GROUP BY t2.empid,t2.catid
ORDER BY t2.empid,t2.catid;
```

### Test:

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> t2.empid,
    ->     t1.catid
    -> ,COUNT(t3.empid) as days
    -> FROM table1 AS t1
    -> LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT empid,t1.catid FROM table2 AS t2 LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON (t1.catid>0)) AS t2
    -> ON (t1.catid=t2.catid)
    -> LEFT JOIN table2 AS t3 ON (t2.empid=t3.empid AND t3.catid=t2.catid)
    -> GROUP BY t2.empid,t2.catid
    -> ORDER BY t2.empid,t2.catid;
+-------+-------+------+
| empid | catid | days |
+-------+-------+------+
|  1000 |     1 |    1 |
|  1000 |     2 |    0 |
|  1000 |     3 |    1 |
|  1001 |     1 |    1 |
|  1001 |     2 |    0 |
|  1001 |     3 |    0 |
|  1002 |     1 |    0 |
|  1002 |     2 |    1 |
|  1002 |     3 |    1 |
+-------+-------+------+
```